# How do I knock over the pins on level W3-4 strike lake?

Tags: paper-mario-sticker-star

Is there a bowling ball somewhere that I use to knock down these pins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [this](http://uk.ign.com/wikis/paper-mario-sticker-star/World_3-4_Strike_Lake) guide on IGN:

> When you find the segment of Wiggler's body, he will join you and a
>   secret path will open to the north. Jump over the bench and keep going
>   north. This way you will find the Bowling Ball. Exit the stage with
>   select, go to Decalburg to convert your new thing to a sticker, and
>   then go back to the Strike Lake.
>
> Make your way until you get in front of the bowling pins. Place the
>   Bowling Ball sticker on the stump at the front of the screen, and then
>   you'll be able to collect the second Comet Sticker!